# RecyclerView Not Displaying Data Received

Tags: java, android, fragment, firebase, android-recyclerview

I am getting the data from Firebase (online data storage) but somehow in my adapter class, the dataset is []. However when I pass in 20 random things using the same class, it works perfectly. Here is the code.

Fragment Class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("http...");
    initListItems();
}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_products, container, false);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));

    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(mDataset);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    return rootView;

}
// Get the data from Firebase and set it to List
private void initListItems() {

    // Attach an listener to read the data at our posts reference
    myFirebaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            System.out.println("There are " + snapshot.getChildrenCount() + "children");

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                title = postSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                description = postSnapshot.child("description").getValue().toString();
                location = postSnapshot.child("location").getValue().toString();
                //This displays the information so it is properly reading data in
                System.out.println("title: " + title  +
                        "description" + description + "location" + location);

                mDataset.add(new ListItem(title, description, location, 0.00, 0.00));


            }

        }
    });
    // If i remove the above code and just put this, the recycleview displays this information
    for (int i = 0; i<20; i++) {
        String name ="This is element #" + i;
        mDataset.add(new ListItem(name, "description", "location", 0.00, 0.00));
    }
}
```

Adapter Class:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private static final String TAG = "MyAdapter";
    private List<ListItem> mDataSet;
    /**
     * Provide a reference to the type of views that you are using (custom ViewHolder)
     */
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private final TextView textView;
        private final ImageView imageView;
        private final TextView textViewLocation;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            // Define click listener for the ViewHolder's View.
            v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                ...
            });
            textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.startupName);
            textViewLocation = (TextView) v.findViewById((R.id.startupLocation));
            imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.startupImage);
        }

        public TextView getTextView() {
            return textView;
        }
        public TextView getTextViewLocation() {
            return textViewLocation;
        }
        public ImageView getImageView() {
            return imageView;
        }

    }



//    When I try to send the data received from Firebase, it prints out [ ] but if i use the random data I created, it works              
public MyAdapter(List<ListItem> dataSet) {
        System.out.println("THE DATASET IS " + dataSet);
        mDataSet = dataSet;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        // Create a new view.
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.row_item, viewGroup, false);

        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Element " + position + " set.");

        // Get element from your dataset at this position and replace the contents of the view with that element
        ...

    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataSet == null ? 0 : mDataSet.size();
    }
}
```

[image: This is picture of recyclerview with the random data]

[image: This is picture of recyclerview with data from firebase]

Does anyone have an idea to why this is happening, why my data from Firebase is not showing up?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `onCreate` you asynchronously go get the data - which might take some time. In the meantime the program flow moves along and you set up the recycler in `onCreateView`, but this happens before you get the response with data, and as a result your `mDataset` is still without values. A while after you get the result and put it in `mDataset`, but I don't see a place where you notify the `RecyclerView` about the change.

So you either have to defer setting up the `RecyclerView` until after you really get the results or notify the `RecyclerView` about the data set update once you get it.

Comment: This is correct, so in your `onDataChange ` after `mDataset.add()` also call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. Note that we're working on adding a RecyclerView adapter to FirebaseUI to solve this problem for you: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android (0.2 should finalize the RecyclerViewAdapter contract, it is on a branch now).

Comment: Thank you very much Frank. All i had to do was add mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); after  mDataset.add(new Startup(title, description, location, 0.00, 0.00));